# Scala spark - Dealing with Hierarchy data tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have data table with hierarchy data model with tree structures. 
For example: 
Here is a sample data row:

```
-------------------------------------------
Id | name    |parentId | path       | depth
-------------------------------------------
55 | Canada  | null    | null       | 0
77 | Ontario |  55     | /55        | 1
100| Toronto |  77     | /55/77     | 2
104| Brampton| 100     | /55/77/100 | 3
```

I am looking to convert those rows into flattening version, sample output would be:

```
-----------------------------------
Id | name     | parentId | depth
------------------------------------
104| Brampton | Toronto  | 3
100| Toronto  | Ontario  | 2
77 | Ontario  | Canada   | 1
55 | Canada   | None     | 0
100| Toronto  | Ontario  | 2
77 | Ontario  | Canada   | 1
55 | Canada   | None     | 0
77 | Ontario  | Canada   | 1
55 | Canada   | None     | 0
55 | Canada   | None     | 0
```

I tried using cartesian or do like n2 search but none of them are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one way:

```
//Creating DF with your data
def getSeq(s:String): Seq[String] = { s.split('|').map(_.trim).toSeq }
var l = getSeq("77 | Ontario |  55     | /55        | 1") :: Nil
l :+= getSeq("55 | Canada  | null    | null       | 0")
l :+= getSeq("100| Toronto |  77     | /55/77     | 2")
l :+= getSeq("104| Brampton| 100     | /55/77/100 | 3")
val df = l.map(x => x match { case Seq(a,b,c,d,e) => (a,b,c,d,e) }).toDF("Id", "name", "parentId", "path", "depth")

//original DF with parentName using a self join
val dfWithPar = df.as("df1").join(df.as("df2"), $"df1.parentId" === $"df2.Id", "leftouter").select($"df1.Id",$"df1.name",$"df1.parentId",$"df1.path",$"df1.depth",$"df2.name".as("parentName"))

// Split path as per requirement and get the exploded DF
val dfExploded = dfWithPar.withColumn("path", regexp_replace($"path", "^/", "")).withColumn("path", split($"path","/")).withColumn("path", explode($"path"))

//Join orig with exploded to get addendum of rows as per individual path placeholders
val dfJoined = dfWithPar.join(dfExploded, dfWithPar.col("Id") === dfExploded.col("path")).select(dfWithPar.col("Id"), dfWithPar.col("name"), dfWithPar.col("parentId"), dfWithPar.col("path"), dfWithPar.col("depth"), dfWithPar.col("parentName"))

//Get the final result by adding the addendum to orig
dfWithPar.union(dfJoined).select($"Id", $"name", $"parentName", $"depth").show

+---+--------+----------+-----+
| Id|    name|parentName|depth|
+---+--------+----------+-----+
| 77| Ontario|    Canada|    1|
| 55|  Canada|      null|    0|
|100| Toronto|   Ontario|    2|
|104|Brampton|   Toronto|    3|
| 77| Ontario|    Canada|    1|
| 77| Ontario|    Canada|    1|
| 55|  Canada|      null|    0|
| 55|  Canada|      null|    0|
| 55|  Canada|      null|    0|
|100| Toronto|   Ontario|    2|
+---+--------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: What if i want the out to be grouped, instead of rows. For example the path will turn into path with actual names instead of the hierachy.

Comment: I am sure there are multiple ways to achieve   but don't have a ready answer. You can post as a new Q.  One way I could think of is to add an additional column while creating `dfExploded` in my answer that captures the index/position of the parent in the path (using `posexplode` perhaps) and then, post self join use a UDAF to create the parent name path.

Answer (score 1):

**Self joins with conditions** and **selecting appropriate columns** should work for you.

*The solution is a bit tricky as you need to find every parent names in path column including the papentId column* which would require `concat_ws`, `split` and `explode` *inbuilt functions*. The rest of the process is `joins`, `selects` and `fills`.

Given dataframe :

```
+---+--------+--------+----------+-----+
|Id |name    |parentId|path      |depth|
+---+--------+--------+----------+-----+
|55 |Canada  |null    |null      |0    |
|77 |Ontario |55      |/55       |1    |
|100|Toronto |77      |/55/77    |2    |
|104|Brampton|100     |/55/77/100|3    |
+---+--------+--------+----------+-----+
```

You can *generate temporary dataframe* for **final join** as

```
val df2 = df.as("table1")
  .join(df.as("table2"), col("table1.parentId") === col("table2.Id"), "left")
  .select(col("table1.Id").as("path"), col("table1.name").as("name"), col("table2.name").as("parentId"), col("table1.depth").as("depth"))
  .na.fill("None")
//    +----+--------+--------+-----+
//    |path|name    |parentId|depth|
//    +----+--------+--------+-----+
//    |55  |Canada  |None    |0    |
//    |77  |Ontario |Canada  |1    |
//    |100 |Toronto |Ontario |2    |
//    |104 |Brampton|Toronto |3    |
//    +----+--------+--------+-----+
```

And the required dataframe can be achieved by doing

```
df.withColumn("path", explode(split(concat_ws("", col("parentId"), col("path")), "/")))
    .as("table1")
    .join(df2.as("table2"), Seq("path"), "right")
    .select(col("table2.path").as("Id"), col("table2.name").as("name"), col("table2.parentId").as("parentId"), col("table2.depth").as("depth"))
    .na.fill("0")
  .show(false)
//    +---+--------+--------+-----+
//    |Id |name    |parentId|depth|
//    +---+--------+--------+-----+
//    |55 |Canada  |None    |0    |
//    |55 |Canada  |None    |0    |
//    |55 |Canada  |None    |0    |
//    |55 |Canada  |None    |0    |
//    |77 |Ontario |Canada  |1    |
//    |77 |Ontario |Canada  |1    |
//    |77 |Ontario |Canada  |1    |
//    |100|Toronto |Ontario |2    |
//    |100|Toronto |Ontario |2    |
//    |104|Brampton|Toronto |3    |
//    +---+--------+--------+-----+
```

**Explanation**

for `|104|Brampton|100     |/55/77/100|3    |` row 
`concat_ws("", col("parentId"), col("path"))` would generate `|104|Brampton|100     |100/55/77/100|3    |` as you can see *100 being concatenated* at the front
`split(concat_ws("", col("parentId"), col("path")), "/")` would generate *array column* as `|104|Brampton|100     |[100, 55, 77, 100]|3    |`
and `explode(split(concat_ws("", col("parentId"), col("path")), "/"))` as a whole would *explode the array column into separate rows* as

```
|104|Brampton|100     |100     |3    |
|104|Brampton|100     |55      |3    |
|104|Brampton|100     |77      |3    |
|104|Brampton|100     |100     |3    |
```

`joins` are much clearer to understand which doesn't need explanation ;)

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("pathtest").setMaster("local")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

var dfA = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  (55, "Canada", -1, "", 0),
  (77, "Ontario", 55, "/55", 1),
  (100, "Toronto", 77, "/55/77", 2),
  (104, "Brampton", 100, "/55/77/100", 3))
)
.toDF("Id", "name", "parentId", "path", "depth")


def getArray = udf((path: String) => {
  if (path.contains("/"))
    path.split("/")
  else
    Array[String](null)
})

val dfB = dfA
    .withColumn("path", getArray(col("path")))
    .withColumn("path", explode(col("path")))
    .toDF()

dfB.as("B").join(dfA.as("A"), $"B.parentId" === $"A.Id", "left")
  .select($"B.Id".as("Id"), $"B.name".as("name"), $"A.name".as("parent"), $"B.depth".as("depth"))
    .show()
```

I have 2 dataframes dfA and dfB which is generated from the first one. dfB is generated with an udf by exploding the array of path. Note that the trick for Canada is to return an empty Array otherwise explode will not generate a row.

dfB looks like this:

```
+---+--------+--------+----+-----+
| Id|    name|parentId|path|depth|
+---+--------+--------+----+-----+
| 55|  Canada|      -1|null|    0|
| 77| Ontario|      55|    |    1|
| 77| Ontario|      55|  55|    1|
|100| Toronto|      77|    |    2|
|100| Toronto|      77|  55|    2|
|100| Toronto|      77|  77|    2|
|104|Brampton|     100|    |    3|
|104|Brampton|     100|  55|    3|
|104|Brampton|     100|  77|    3|
|104|Brampton|     100| 100|    3|
+---+--------+--------+----+-----+
```

And the final results as next:

```
+---+--------+-------+-----+
| Id|    name| parent|depth|
+---+--------+-------+-----+
| 55|  Canada|   null|    0|
| 77| Ontario| Canada|    1|
| 77| Ontario| Canada|    1|
|100| Toronto|Ontario|    2|
|100| Toronto|Ontario|    2|
|100| Toronto|Ontario|    2|
|104|Brampton|Toronto|    3|
|104|Brampton|Toronto|    3|
|104|Brampton|Toronto|    3|
|104|Brampton|Toronto|    3|
+---+--------+-------+-----+
```