# Spark scala - convert an array into values from the same table in a Hierarchy type table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

have data table with hierarchy data model with tree structures. For example: Here is a sample data row:

```
-------------------------------------------
Id | name    |parentId | path       | depth
-------------------------------------------
55 | Canada  | null    | null       | 0
77 | Ontario |  55     | /55        | 1
100| Toronto |  77     | /55/77     | 2
104| Brampton| 100     | /55/77/100 | 3
```

I am looking to convert those rows into flattening version, sample output would be:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Id | name    |parentId | path       | depth | pathNames
-------------------------------------------------------
55 | Canada  | null    | null       | 0 .   | None
77 | Ontario |  55     | /55        | 1 .   | Canada
100| Toronto |  77     | /55/77     | 2 .   | Canada, Ontario
104| Brampton| 100     | /55/77/100 | 3 .   | Canada, Ontario, Toronto
```

To simply how the PathFullNames is generated, it comes from the same table matching on the ids from the path. So in the above example
/55/77/100 is equal to /Canada/Ontario/Toronto

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala spark - Dealing with Hierarchy data tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371355/scala-spark-dealing-with-hierarchy-data-tables)

Comment: Almost similar but different outpu

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you explained where the `pathNames` come from (i.e. looked up by `Id`) rather than making the reader figure this out for themselves.

Comment: Oh okay, sure I can make it more clear. I thought it was obvious from looking at the Path column to understand pathFullName columns

Comment: [Graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/) could be useful in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help specifically with your problem:

You can create a dict from columns *Id* and *name*

```
// Generate a dict: Id -> name
val idMap = test.distinct.select($"Id", $"name").rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(0), r.getString(1))).collectAsMap
```

then define a [UDF](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html) (user defined function) that will map the string

> /55/77

to the string

> Canada,Ontario

```
val pathMap = udf((p: String) => p.split("/").filter(_!="").map(id => idMap(id.toInt)).mkString(","))
```

finally, add a new column using this UDF and the *path* column

```
test.select(col("*"), when($"path".isNull, "None").otherwise(pathMap($"path")).as("pathNames")).show(false)
```

this gives you the dataframe you want:

```
+---+--------+--------+----------+-----+----------------------+
|Id |name    |parentId|path      |depth|pathNames             |
+---+--------+--------+----------+-----+----------------------+
|55 |Canada  |null    |null      |0    |None                  |
|77 |Ontario |55      |/55       |1    |Canada                |
|100|Toronto |77      |/55/77    |2    |Canada,Ontario        |
|104|Brampton|100     |/55/77/100|3    |Canada,Ontario,Toronto|
+---+--------+--------+----------+-----+----------------------+
```

Hope this will help you!

pd: Sorry for my english